# What is the Rails Migration for creating a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, database-migration, rails-migrations

What is the Rails Migration for creating a table?

I tried this migration generator:

```
$ rails g migration CreateQuestions user:references question_title:string question_text:text approved:boolean
```

This creates a migration that seems to be missing the usual `id` and `timestamps` fields. Did I mess up my generator?

```
class CreateQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :questions do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.string :question_title
      t.text :question_text
      t.boolean :approved
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want to generate a model (which creates the table)?

Comment: ah right, so I should be doing `rails g model Questions user:references question_title:string question_text:text approved:boolean`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. ["A primary key column called id will also be added implicitly, as it's the default primary key for all Active Record models."](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#migration-overview)
2. If you wanna add the `timestamps`, add this to your migration file:

   ```
   t.timestamps
   ```

Comment: is there no way to include it from the generator?

Comment: looks like just having 'timestamps' in the generator did it